# Flashing Samsung Galaxy Note 3 with Android on Linux

Tags: rom-flashing, 4.4-kitkat, linux, stock-android, samsung-galaxy-note-3

Is there a way to flash my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 with stock rom(Android KitKat 4.4.2) in Linux(any distribution)?

EDIT: I can't figure out how to flash [this](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/3/?download=28946) firmware with Heimdall. All I can find is different files and different devices.

EDIT:[Here](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/tree/master/Linux) are the instructions building a Heimdall firmware package.

EDIT: I found a post on XDA saying that Heimdall doens't support KitKat 4.4.2, I got the same error as that guy:ERROR: Failed to send request to end PIT file transfer!
ERROR: Failed to download PIT file! When trying to download the PIT file for my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For flashing Samsung devices on operating systems other than Windows, you might wish to take a look at our [heimdall](/questions/tagged/heimdall) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/heimdall/info):

> Heimdall is a cross-platform open-source tool suite used to flash firmware (aka ROMs) onto Samsung mobile devices

Thought your device doesn't seem to be explicitly mentioned as being "officially tested" on the [projects homepage](http://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/), the page writes:

> Users have reported success with a wide variety of Samsung's mobile phones and tablets from all around the world.

[image: Heimdall (click for larger variant)]
<sup>Heimdall (Source: [WebUpd8.Org](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/heimdall-odin-alternative-that-runs-on.html); click image for larger variant)</sup>

---

**Update:** If Heimdall somehow doesn't fit your needs, according to our [odin tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/odin/info) there's also [JOdin3](http://www.xda-developers.com/meet-jodin3-a-web-tool-that-flashes-your-samsung-device/) which works browser based. Haven't tried that (no Sammy here), but might be worth a look.